# A finite simplicial complex is locally connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Prove that for any finite simplicial complex $K$, its topological realization $|K|$ is locally connected.

We know that $|K|$ consists of equivalence classes. Let $[x]\in |K|$. Denote the quotient collapsing map as $q:D \to |K|$, from the disjoint union of simplexes to its realization.

If there is only one element in the equivalence class $[x]$, then $q^{-1}([x])$ belongs to exactly one of simplexes in $K$ (more precisely, $q^{-1}([x])$ belongs to the interior of one of simplexes in $K$.

Therefore, for any open set $U$ in $|K|$ containing $[x]$, we can always find open $V\subset U$ containing $[x]$ such that $q^{-1}(V)$ is a subset of the interior of one simplex in $K$. Hence, $q^{-1}(V)$ is connected and hence $V$ is connected. Thus $|K|$ is locally connected at $[x]$, where there is only one element in $[x]$.

What if $[x]$ contains more than one element? For example, if $[x]$ is on the edge of a tetrahedron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space $X$ is locally connected if whenever $x\in U$ where $U$
is open in $X$, there is an open connected $V$ with $x\in V\subseteq U$.

A finite simplicial complex can be realised geometrically as a collection of faces of some simplex, say as the simplex $\Delta$ whose vertices are
the standard basis vectors $e_1,\ldots,e_N$ of $\Bbb R^N$.
Let $x\in U\subseteq|K|\subseteq\Delta$ where $U$ is open in $\Delta$. We can
assume that $U=B_\epsilon(x)\cap |K|$ where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is a Euclidean ball in $\Bbb R^N$. Write $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ where $\sum_i x_i=1$
and all $x_i\ge 0$.
Let $V=B_\eta(x)\cap |K|$ where we ensure $0<\eta<\epsilon$ and $\eta<x_i$
for all nonzero $x_i$. Then the only simplices of $|K|$ that $V$
meets are those containing $x$, and the intersection of $B_\eta(x)$
with any such simplex is a connected set containing $x$. Then $V$ is connected.

Comment: Why intersection of $B_\eta(x)$ with any such simplex is connected?

Comment: @Kenneth.K convexity

Comment: and why $\eta<x_i$ for all nonzero $x_i$?

Comment: @Kenneth.K to avoid $V$ meeting a simplex not containing $x$.